# Extract numbers from a string into an array in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, type-conversion

I have a string that is a string of ids 
-->  "[6947,7182]"

I want to extract the numbers into an array and also want to keep it simple since the number of ids enclosed can be quite a lot .

I am listing an option that I have tried :

```
Regex.Split(this.request["ids"],@"\D+")

result :
{string[4]}
    [0]: ""
    [1]: "6947"
    [2]: "7182"
    [3]: ""
```

This gives me extra two value at index 0 and 3 , any alternative for this or any better approach for this .

Comment: This looks like JSON. (It _is_ a valid JSON string that can be parsed as an array containing two integers.) There’s probably some way of parsing JSON in C#.

Comment: No , this is not a json !

Comment: Internally for Api we are passing the information in this way

Comment: `Regex.Matches(str, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value)`

Comment: Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(string)` to convert string into a list of ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get an array of strings:

```
ids.Substring(1, ids.Length - 2).Split(',')
```